# SSL : Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

The server specifically mentioned to use these two ciphers

> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
>    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-nio-8080-exec-3, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1487315819 bytes = { 91, 21, 137, 185, 34, 110, 50, 54, 243, 46, 201, 26, 211, 196, 2, 180, 194, 116, 50, 153, 193, 101, 112, 52, 55, 244, 198, 134 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=connect.pointclickcare.com]
***
http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 202
http-nio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-nio-8080-exec-3, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
http-nio-8080-exec-3, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-3, called closeInternal(true)
```

And then I get

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I am using HttpsURLConnection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE), had to replace some jar files in the /lib/security folder in $JAVA_HOME path.

[Link to use JCE](https://www.attachmate.com/documentation/rweb/rweb-installguide/data/b1gdutii.htm)

Answer (score 2):

> The server specifically mentioned to use these two ciphers
>
> ```
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> ```

If these are the only ciphers the server supports than the server supports no ciphers which are supported by the client. The list of ciphers supported by the client can be seen in the debug output:

```
 Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,  ...
```

And if you look at the original debug output you see that there are *SHA384 ciphers which means that no ciphers accepted by the server are offered by the client.

Comment: How do I make my client accept these particular cipher suites

Comment: @M.Ron: I have no idea about your specific client and the code you use but TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 should be enabled by default with Java 8. Of course local configurations or code might override these defaults.

Comment: I used this             SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            availableCiphers = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites(); : It returns all the cipher except the one's the server specified.

Answer (score 0):

Like M.Ron has mentioned, you need to install JCE extension for you JVM. 
Basicly this problem is due to the mismatch cipher between your local JAVA and the https site.

1: Use https://www.ssllabs.com/ to check if your REST API supports java,
[check this image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEaes.png)

2: Check the solution here i just tired, it works for me and save my day!

[How to debug the ssl connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550013/how-to-debug-the-ssl-connection-error)